# Extract elements by tag or class name from DOM

Tags: php, parsing, html-content-extraction

I try use class PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser for extract images by class name but i can´t get this

**I use this wth this class :**

```
$file=file_get_contents("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en");

$html = str_get_html($file);

$html->find('img', 1)->class = 'screenshot';

//$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

echo $html;
```

But i can´t get this i don´t know if i can do this with other class or functions , it´s possible get ? , thank´s , regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "screenshot" is the image's class name:

`foreach ($html->find('img.screenshot') as $img) {
    // do what you want with $img
}`

You should read the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: And for example extract the url of video of youtube : <span class="preview-overlay-container" data-docid="com.cleanmaster.mguard" data-video-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yenJQQJlFqg?ps=play&amp;vq=large&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;authuser=0"> 

<span class="play-action-container" data-video-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yenJQQJlFqg?ps=play&amp;vq=large&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;authuser=0"> 

Regards

Comment: Something like this would work: `foreach ($html->find('.preview-overlay-container') as $video) { $url = $video->getAttribute('data-video-url'); }`

Comment: Thank´s a lot i understand how works , nice , thank´s for the help